# MVC4 - Server cannot set status after HTTP headers have been sent

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, redirect

After moving to MVC4 from MVC3, this line

```
Return Redirect("https://secure.mysite.com/account/signup")
```

started to throw exception

```
Server cannot set status after HTTP headers have been sent
```

This is the method in

```
Function signup() As ActionResult

    Dim HTTP_HOST = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST")

    If Request.IsSecureConnection = False Or HTTP_HOST <> "secure.mysite.com" Then
        Return Redirect("https://secure.mysite.com/account/signup")
    End If


    'more code here

     Return View(_viewModel)
End Function
```

Can't figure this out because Return redirect line above is the first time session is being sent back.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had a similar issue in my code where I can see ELMAH logging: `System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Server cannot set status after HTTP headers have been sent.`

I think the exception is because Response.End and Response.Redirect do not cause a thread abort in MVC applications (Response.Redirect is not really a part of the MVC pipeline).

Try:

```
return new RedirectResult("https://secure.mysite.com/account/signup", true);
```